# ¿Por qué si no se pone "break" en un case, este salta hacia los demás "cases"?

Tags: c++, switch

Pongamos un ejemplo:

Tengo este siguiente `switch`:

```
 switch(numero){
        case 1: std::cout<<"El numero es uno"<<std::endl;
        case 5: std::cout<<"Si el numero es uno, saltara a este case (el case 5)"<<std::endl; 
    }
```

Ahora, lo que no entiendo es, ¿Por qué si no se pone `break` en un `case`, ese `case` saltará a otros `cases`?

Pienso que no debería saltar hacia el `case 5` si el `case` es 1; ya que debería de evaluar si el numero actual (1) corresponde al numero 5, y eso debería de dar `false`, y así, nunca a entrar al `case 5` pero de todas formas entra...

#### ¿Qué he intentado?

He intentado repasar los `switchs()`, en un video de [Absolute](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvnoM0R1sDKm-YCPifEso_g), llamado: [SWITCH en 2 Minutos!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPKylS8ifuI&list=PL-9YbO84eUcee9CWgvHTqUQszoM9bGm96&index=6), y más o menos en el minuto: [1:21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPKylS8ifuI&t=81s), explica algo sobre el `break`, pero no explicó a detalle el `break` y como funciona en el `switch` (o tal vez lo explicó en otro video (cosa que dudo bastante)).

#### <s>Código</s>

<s>No hace falta poner nada en este encabezado.</s>

#### Resumen

> > ¿Por qué si no se pone `break` en un `case`, ese `case` saltará a otros `cases`?

Comment: La respuesta a tu duda está en este enlace https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/switch-statement-cpp?view=msvc-160#switch-statement-behavior

Comment: **Porque el lenguaje es así**.

Comment: Así es como diseñaron C++, esa es la razón que buscas. Si pruebas otros lenguajes de programación, como [Pawn](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawn), te darás cuenta que no necesitas usar el `break` en cada `case`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sin el `break`, el programa pasa al siguiente `case`, ejecutando todos los `case` hasta que encuentre un `break` o haya terminado de recorrer el ciclo `switch`.

Cabe recordar que `switch` no reemplaza `if ... else` en muchos lenguajes de programación. La ventaja de `switch` es que permite coincidir varias condiciones al tiempo.

[Aquí](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/162575) podemos encontrar un buen ejemplo:

```
public Season SeasonFromMonth(Month month)
{
    Season season;
    switch (month)
    {
        case Month.December:
        case Month.January:
        case Month.February:
            season = Season.Winter;
            break;

        case Month.March:
        case Month.April:
        case Month.May:
            season = Season.Spring;
            break;

        case Month.June:
        case Month.July:
        case Month.August:
            season = Season.Summer;
            break;

        default:
            season = Season.Autumn;
            break;
    }

    return season;
}
```